# Programmatically remove exposed filter in a view

Tags: views

I would like to remove a certain exposed filter on the **taxonomy term** view when certain conditions in the URL are met.

For example, I want to remove the "**Color**" exposed filter when the user is seeing the **/color/red** taxonomy term page, leaving only the "**Shape**" filter available.

Or remove the "**Shape**" exposed filter on the **/shape/square** page, leaving only the "**Color**" one.

The only code I could come up with is this, which is ugly and doesn't even work.

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view){
      if( CONDITIONS_ARE_MET ) {
         unset($view->filter['field_color_tid']);
         unset($view->exposed_data['field_color_tid']);
         unset($view->exposed_raw_input['field_color_tid']);
      }
}
```

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

This is the code in mmo_views_alters:

```
function mmo_views_alters_views_pre_build(&$view){
    //dpm($view);
    unset($view->filter['field_tipologia_tid']);
}
```

This is the exported view: http://pastebin.com/JrYDmtZQ

It has **4 filters, and 3 of them are exposed**. 
I'm using **BEF** for displaying them, which generated another warning (*undefined index filter-field_tipologia_tid*) that I solved by patching **better_exposed_filters_exposed_form_plugin.inc**, line 896:

```
if( isset($form['#info']["filter-$label"]['value']) )
        $field_id = $form['#info']["filter-$label"]['value'];
else continue;
```

The warnings that I'm not able to solve are:

> Notice: Undefined index: field_tipologia_tid in
>   views_handler_filter_term_node_tid->exposed_validate() (linea 258 di
>   /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/modules/taxonomy/views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: field_tipologia_tid in
>   views_handler_filter_term_node_tid->exposed_validate() (linea 259 di
>   /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/modules/taxonomy/views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc).

They appear even with BEF disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `hook_views_pre_build()` and unset using `unset($view->filter['field_color_tid']);`

Else, you can also try altering the exposed form in `hook_form_alter()` using the code `$form['field_tipologia_tid']['#access']=FALSE;`

Comment: thanks, that works, although I get 2 similar warnings:

Notice: Undefined index: field_tipologia_tid in views_handler_filter_term_node_tid->exposed_validate()


Notice: Undefined index: field_tipologia_tid in views_handler_filter_term_node_tid->exposed_validate() (line 259 in /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/modules/taxonomy/views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc)

Comment: can you share the code written in `hook_views_pre_build()` and how many filters you have and how many you are exposing .

Comment: sure, I've edited the original post.

Comment: @Sifro I have updated the answer, try it